# How to test a hybrid Swing / Compose Desktop application

Tags: swing, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

We are migrating a large Swing application to Compose Desktop and are intending to replace Swing components by compose components within the existing Swing UI, e.g. a Composable component with TextFields into a Swing container like `JPanel`. We are using a ComposePanel to do this, and that works fine. The individual compose components can be unit-tested OK with ComposeTestRule. However, we need higher level tests of the application containing both the Swing components and the new components which means sending keyboard & mouse input to the "embedded" compose components and also reading their state. Is there a way to do this? Ideally, we'd like the matchers and assertions provided by `ComposeTestRule`, but which would be available even if the composable is contained in a `ComposePanel` or `ComposeWindow`.

Here is a simple example of what we are trying to achieve.
The state of `MyTextField` can be easily unit-tested using `ComposeTestRule`:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
@Test
fun `text field should be initialised to bar and also editable`()  {
    with (composeTestRule) {
        setContent {
            MyTextField()
        }
        onNodeWithText("bar").assertExists()
        onNodeWithTag("myTextField").performTextInput("foo ")
        onNodeWithText("foo bar").assertExists()
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun MyTextField() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("bar") }
    MaterialTheme {
        TextField(
            value =text,
            onValueChange = { changedText ->
                text = changedText
                println("changedText = ${changedText}")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.testTag("myTextField")
        )
    }
}
```

but when it's embedded in a JFrame using ComposePanel, how does one programatically perform the same sort of interactions and checks?

[image]

```
fun main() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
        val composePanel = ComposePanel().apply {
            setContent {
                MyTextField()
            }
        }
        with(JFrame("compose test")) {
            add(composePanel)
            setSize(400, 200)
            isVisible = true
        }
    }
} (edited)
```

Comment: Why not use [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html)? It was custom built for this exact use case, and better yet, it is framework-agnostic. It does not care if you are using Swing/AWT/Compose/etc.

Comment: Robot is great for interacting with Swing/AWT components. In fact, we use assertj-swing fixtures (which are built on Robot) for all our Swing UI testing. We do this by providing each Swing component with a name, then the fixture can find the component with that name in the hierarchy and either read its state or provide keyboard/mouse input to it. This approach does not translate to compose components. Have you been able to read the state of a compose component using Robot, or enter text into a composable TextView using Robot?

Comment: I absolutely have. In fact, the method you described above is the framework-dependent way of doing it. I have been describing the framework-agnostic one. I have accessibility features attached to all of my controls, and I use those as framework-agnostic "handles" for the Robot to grab onto. From there, it's easy to make any controls framework-agnostic. Then, it does not matter if you are doing things through Swing/Compose/etc. They all can be interacted with through Robot.

Comment: That sounds great. Could you perhaps show a simple code example that does this. For example, how would you add accessibility features to the TextView control above so that Robot could send it keyboard input and so that its state ("foo bar") could be read when it's displayed in the JFrame.

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer. Not now though, I have another answer that I haven't finished up yet that I need to do first. But as a sneak peek -- you can do it a few different ways. One way is through [Mnemonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_(keyboard)). It's the most popular method, but you may have to tweak it slightly for it to work with text boxes (character encoding issues and key shortcuts, etc). This method adds accessibility key combos to all of your UI Controls, allowing you to navigate your entire UI via key combos. Then from there, just tell Robot to use the key combos.

Comment: Hi. Do you have time to provide an answer for this, i.e. reading from and writing to a TextField which is embedded in a Swing application? I'm starting to think that in this version of compose for desktop (1.5.11) these higher-level testing facilities are just not available.

Comment: Hello Lindsay, I have not forgotten this. Unfortunately, I am still tied up. Not sure when I will be able to get a full solution. If you are fine with an undeveloped one, however, let me know I can type up a very rudimentary prototype. And to be clear, something that is more pseudocode than it is a working solution.

Comment: Hi David, I'm happy to have a look at pseudocode, but it's important that the functions in the pseudocode are actually available in compose desktop